# Use v-menu for items in v-list

Tags: vue.js, menu, vuetify.js

I use ‘attach’ of v-menu to attach to item in v-list.

```
<v-menu v-model="showMenu" :attach="itemAttachID" :close-on-click="false" :offset-x="true" :offset-y="true">
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="300" tile>
            <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in itemBookmark" :key="index"
                 @click="addCategoryForPost(item)">
            <v-list-item-title class="d-block text-truncate" max-width="250">{{item.name}}</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-icon v-if="item.check">
                 <v-icon class="mdi mdi-check"></v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

But I can not correct position of menu to left or right of item. Thanks for support.